# Unexpected syntax error in react build chunk files and manifest json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

I want to serve my react app from {baseurl}/admin/ . I did some research and found out this solution-

My express code-

```
app.use('/admin/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/admin/frontend/')));
app.get('/admin/*', (req, res, next) => 
{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/admin/frontend/index.html'));
});
```

I also added "homepage" in my package.json file-

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
"homepage": "."
```

Also changed the starturl in manifest.json

```
"start_url": "./index.html",
```

Also I have changed base url of my react router-

```
<Router basename="/admin">
...
</Router>
```

Now this setup works fine when the urls are like this-
localhost:5000/admin/{something}
but fails when url goes more deep like-
localhost:5000/admin/{something}/....

When I try to load urls like above chrome console gives me this error -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' 2.bb5676a4.chunk.js:1 
​Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' main.0173e5ea.chunk.js:1
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Could you add your directory structure?  What's under __dirname/admin/frontend?

Comment: @dx_over_dt react build files

Comment: Try navigating to `/admin/frontend/main.0173e5ea.chunk.js`.  My hunch is now that you'll get your index.html file.

Comment: @dx_over_dt yeh

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I've found, since your index file is named `index.html` is to just remove your `app.get('/*', ...)` line altogether.

```js
app.use('/admin/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/admin/frontend/')));
```

That should be sufficient for serving both `/admin/` and `/admin/index.html`.

If you need to use a different default route, add the `index` option to your `express.static()` call:

```js
app.use('/admin/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/admin/frontend'), { 
    index: 'index.htm' 
}));
```

Comment: This loads file when I go localhost:5000/admin but shows not found on any other like localhost:5000/admin/login.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  It works perfectly on my machine.  I guess copy and paste what you have..?